# How is it possible to get p.exitcode=None right after p.terminate()?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

The following code, sometimes returns as error that python can't compare `None` with an integer.

This means that `p.exitcode` is `None` even after `p.terminate()`. However in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) is stated that

> This (the exitcode) will be `None` if the process has not yet terminated.

How is this possible?

The code:

```
for j in range(3):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target = functions_that_hangs, args = (arguments,))
    p.start()
    p.join(180)

    if p.is_alive: # used to check if process is still runing
        p.terminate()

    if p.exitcode >= 0 : # used to check if process completed successfully 
        break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`terminate()` [doesn't literally terminate the process](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate):

> On POSIX OSs the method sends SIGTERM to the child. On Windows the Win32 API function TerminateProcess() is called to stop the child.

Both these operations are asynchronous: they request the process to terminate, but don't wait for actual termination.

To wait for actual termination (which guarantees availability of `exitcode`), use [`wait()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait):

```
if p.is_alive:
    p.terminate()
    p.wait()
```

`wait()` returns the exit code, and since Python 3.3 it takes a `timeout` argument, so you can shorten your code to:

```
for j in range(3):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(...)
    p.start()
    exitcode = p.wait(180)
    if exitcode >= 0:
        break
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! All popen methods are asynchronous? I am trying to get how someone understands that form this documentation

Comment: It helps to know C and the underlying set of system calls (on Unix) like `fork`, `exec` and `wait`. But of course, documentation should never assume that the reader happens to know such details. On the other hand, process management is inherently a bit platform-specific.

Comment: @Phineas - you are right that the docs are vague. It does different things on different systems - sends a signal on linux, calls TerminateProcess on Windows. Those are both async calls. On linux, processes may ignore the signal or use it for other purposes. For instance, some need 2 signals to terminate. I do terminate, proc.wait(1), if still alive, terminate again, wait 3, if still alive kill and wait 10.

Comment: The important part is that ``Popen.terminate`` *starts* terminating the process. It does not *wait* until the process is terminated. The docs aren't so much vague but pedantically specific – *no call* waits for completion unless explicitly documented to do so.